# Can pointers manipulate memory at will?

Tags: c

```
int a=10;
char *b ;
b=(char*)&a;
strcpy(b,"xxxxx");
printf("%s",b);
```

The compilation can pass, but the program exits with an error. Why doesn't this work? What is the mechanism of realization?

Comment: You can't copy a string of 5 characters (+1 null terminator) into a memory which has a room for one `int` only (well, at least on your system which probably have 4-byte ints).

Comment: `Can pointers manipulate memory at will?` - no, contrary to popular beliefs, programs do not have a will of their own.

Comment: @SergeyA Well, maybe pointers have? :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. sometimes it seems like they do, and quite evil indeed.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that, in your C implementation, `int` is four bytes. The C standard defines a `char` to use one byte. So `b = (char *) &a;` sets `b` to point the first byte of the four that make up `a`. We do not know what lies after those four bytes.

`strcpy(b, "xxxxx");` asks `strcpy` to copy six bytes (the five “x” characters and a terminating null character) to the memory pointed to by `b`. In the simplest case, this will overwrite two bytes beyond `a`. This can disrupt your program in a variety of ways—it can corrupt some other data the compiler stored there, it can make your stack frame unusable, it can corrupt a return address, and other things can go wrong.

Additionally, when the compiler translates and optimizes your program, it relies on guarantees made to it by the C standard, such as that the operation `strcpy(b, …)` will not write outside of the properly defined object pointed to by `b`, which is `a`. When you violate those guarantees, the C standard does not define the resulting behavior, and the translations and optimizations made by the compiler may cause your program to go awry in unexpected ways.

Comment: Thanks，I understand!

Answer (score 1):

```
int a=10;
char *b ;
b=(char*)&a;
strcpy(b,"xxxxx");
printf("%s",b);
```

> Why doesn't this work?

This doesn't work because strcpy() copy 6 characters (5 times 'x' and one nul terminator) to the address pointed by `b` and there is not enough room for that, at least if the compiler you used store `int` type into 32bits (4 bytes).

You didn't showed the full code, but assuming `a` is a local variable, it is allocated on the stack. You overflow the space allocated for variable `a` and this means you overwrite something on the stack. That data on the stack is essential for program continuation and being overwritten it crashes the system.

Answer (score 0):

"at will"?  No they are actually sentient!

If code does not behave as you expect it is because you have a semantic error - that is code that is syntactically valid (i.e. it compiles) but does not mean what you think it does when executed according to the rules of the language.

Moreover as systems level language C does not protect you from doing invalid things to the execution environment - i.e. runtime errors, and such errors generally have *undefined* behaviour.

In this case:

b=(char*)&a;
strcpy(b,"xxxxx");

`b` points to an object of `int` size.  On Windows or any 32 bit system, that will normally be 4 bytes.  You then copy *6* bytes to it, overrunning its space.  The effect of this is undefined, but it is likely that it will corrupt some adjacent variable in memory or the function return address.

If `b` were corrupted by the `strcpy()` error, trying to print the string at `b` would cause a run-time error is `b` were no longer a valid address.

If the return address were corrupted, the program would fail when you return from the calling function.

In either case the precise behaviour is not defined, and may not be trapped; it depends on when gets corrupted, what value the corrupted data takes, and how and when that corrupted data is used.

You will be able to observe the effects on the variables and/or call stack by running and stepping this code in a debugger.